# SQL Server query syntax (sub queries, brackets and CASE WHEN)

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join, case-when

I have an issue with a query I am trying to run below. I've covered and closed all brackets but SQL Server still highlights

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

at the last bracket just by `AS REV`

```
SELECT 
    spot.spotid, rev.revenue 
FROM 
    [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_Spot] AS SPOT
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         CASE 
            WHEN spot2.status = '4'
                THEN spotcc.mediacost * 5
            WHEN spot2.status IN ('7','8')
                THEN spotcc.mediacost * 20
         END AS revenue
     FROM
         (SELECT * 
          FROM [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_Spot] AS SPOT2
          INNER JOIN [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_SpotCalculation] AS SPOTCC ON spot2.spotid = spotcc.spotid)
    ) AS REV ON spot.spotid = rev.spotid
```

I'm kinda at a loss here. I hope its obvious what I'm trying to achieve overall i.e. inner join the `T_MED_Spot` table with the sub query named as `REV` using the spotid.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use spot2.status there, not in scope.

Comment: you didn't alias your inner query. Change `)) AS REV` to `) as T ) AS REV` Then in the outer case refer to `T` not `spot2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.spotid, 
    CASE 
        WHEN s.[status] = '4' THEN c.mediacost * 5
        WHEN s.[status] IN ('7','8') THEN c.mediacost * 20
    END AS revenue
FROM [dbo].[T_MED_Spot] s
JOIN [dbo].[T_MED_SpotCalculation] c ON c.spotid = s.spotid
```

check this query...

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
SELECT spot.spotid, rev.revenue 
FROM [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_Spot] AS SPOT
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN T.status = '4'
                THEN T.mediacost*5
            WHEN T.status IN ('7','8')
                THEN T.mediacost*20
            END AS revenue, spotid
    FROM (SELECT * FROM [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_Spot] AS SPOT2
            INNER JOIN [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_SpotCalculation] AS SPOTCC 
ON spot2.spotid = spotcc.spotid) AS T ) AS REV
ON spot.spotid = rev.spotid
```

You didn't alias your inner query

Comment: Nick had to modify your code as I was getting invalid column errors.
`SELECT spot.spotid, rev.revenue 
FROM [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_Spot] AS SPOT
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN T.status = '4'
                THEN T.mediacost*5
            WHEN T.status IN ('7','8')
                THEN T.mediacost*20
            END AS revenue, *
    FROM (SELECT spot2.spotid, spot2.status, spotcc.mediacost FROM [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_Spot] AS SPOT2
            INNER JOIN [Media].[dbo].[T_MED_SpotCalculation] AS SPOTCC 
ON spot2.spotid = spotcc.spotid) AS T) AS REV
ON spot.spotid = rev.spotid`

Comment: See if my edited one works. Instead of `*` it uses a specifc column list. One problem with * is if for example you add a same named column to a different table, your select will throw an ambiguous column name error and stop working.

Answer (score 0):

you named the first INNER JOIN Subquery `AS REV` but there is no alias for the second subquery.